# Making a frame part of the Selected Item in a Listbox, similar to the PowerPoint slide selector

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, frame, listboxitem

I'm making a program similar to powerpoint, for changing some slides that display production data. I'm working on the slide selector part that usually appears on the left side of the screen. You choose a slide and it's displayed larger on the main part of my grid. I've made slide templates out of other pages, which I host in frames. Note: using C#

To do the slide selector, I made a listbox with the following DataTemplate:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SlideSelector">
        <Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" Padding="3" CornerRadius="5" Height="120" Width="200">
            <Viewbox>
                <Frame Height="656" Width="1360"  Source ="{Binding Path=SlideURL}"/>
            </Viewbox>
            </Border>
     </DataTemplate>
```

The Listbox:

```
<ListBox Name="SlideSelectorListBox" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSlide}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Slides}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SlideSelector}"/>
```

The items are added via an observable collection that is bound to the itemsource. Each Frame navigates to it's slide template via the binding to the SlideURL in the data template.

My problem is, this displays interactive pages stacked in the listbox and I can only select the item by clicking on the border of the item. I don't want them to be interactive on the listbox, I just want it to be a picture of the slide, that updates as they change it. Is there a way to show the frame but not have it enabled, and have the clicks on it select that item in the list box?

Bonus points: Passing Parameters to those pages when I add them to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hosting the frames, you could instead host runtime generated images of the frame.  Really what you could do is on your Slide object store an image property that is updated occasionally if a property has changed and bind an image control to that.

You can create an image from a wpf element pretty easily.

```
    Public Shared Function GetBitmapSource(ByVal element As FrameworkElement) As BitmapSource

        Dim visual As New DrawingVisual()
        Dim context As DrawingContext = visual.RenderOpen()
        Dim elementBrush As New VisualBrush(element)
        Dim w As Integer = CInt(element.ActualWidth)
        Dim h As Integer = CInt(element.ActualHeight)
        context.DrawRectangle(elementBrush, Nothing, New Rect(0, 0, w, h))
        context.Close()

        Dim bitmap As New RenderTargetBitmap(w, h, 96, 96, PixelFormats.[Default])
        bitmap.Render(visual)
        Return bitmap
    End Function
```

To use, pull the BitmapSource into a rectangles Fill as a imagebrush:

```
Me.rectFormPreview.Fill = New ImageBrush(_objViewFolders(Me.lbFormList.SelectedIndex).ViewBitmapSource)
```

You could have the BitmapSource as a property on the class and pass that through a converter (messy in my opinion) or you could have a property of type ImageBrush instead (preferable methinks).

Comment: hmm, I'm working in C#, so I'll have to try and translate your syntax

Comment: kk, I got all the syntax changed over, so you're thinking I can pass the page as an element and get an image of it?

Comment: I'm guessing it's not as simple as:
bitmapImage = GetBitmapSource(myPageView.xaml);

Comment: Not quite, sorry. I have added additional code to show how to use the BitmapSource...

Comment: Awesome, that worked pretty well. Marking as an acceptable answer for this problem unless anyone has a more elegant solution. Thank you for taking the time to help me out CodeWarrior!

Comment: No problem!  It is what I am all about.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to add on top of the 'Frame' a rectangle filled, with alpha set as low as possible to see through your frame. Like that, the mouse will interact with the rectangle.

Comment: How would I add a rectangle on top on it? Do you have a code snippet?

Comment: <Viewbox> <Grid> <Frame Height="656" Width="1360" Source ="{Binding Path=SlideURL}"/> <Rectangle Fill="#0BF29292" /> </Grid> </Viewbox>

Comment: Question: why do you specify the height/width of the frame as long as it's in the listbox anyway? It should get the size of the listboxitem, the rest will be cropped i guess.